# IFC function throwing error in IN operator

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Has anyone encountered the below error:

```
options symbolgen mprint mlogic minoperator;
%macro test /minoperator mindelimiter=',';
%let var1 = EXPORT;
%if &var1 in (EXPORT, TEST,TEST1) %then %let var_final1=1;
%put &=var_final1.;
%let var_final2 = %sysfunc(ifc(&var1= EXPORT,1,2));
%put &=var_final2;
%let var_final3 = %sysfunc(ifc(&var1 in (EXPORT, TEST,TEST1),1,2));
%put &var_final3;
%mend;
%test;
```

var_final1 and var_final2 are working okay, whereas, for var_final3 where we have ifc function, i get the below error:

```
ERROR: Argument 1 to function IFC referenced by the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function is not a number.
ERROR: Invalid arguments detected in %SYSCALL, %SYSFUNC, or %QSYSFUNC argument list.  Execution of %SYSCALL statement or %SYSFUNC 
       or %QSYSFUNC function reference is terminated.
```

Not sure why the IN operator does not work with IFC or IFN functions?

Can anyone please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is a very tricky job %SYSFUNC() has been given. It has to figure out how to convert your macro text into variables/expressions it can pass to the function it is trying to call.  In this case it cannot figure out the `IN` operator.  Perhaps it doesn't know about the MINOPERATOR option.

You can fix it by making its problem easier by adding an explicit call to `%EVAL()` so that all that it needs to pass to the IFN() function is the resulting zero or one.

```
%let var_final3 = %sysfunc(ifc(%eval(&var1 in (EXPORT, TEST,TEST1)),1,2));
```

Comment: That's a much nicer way to use the `IN` operator in macros than configuring the `MINOPERATOR` option...

Comment: @RobertPenridge Note the posted code IS using macro code since it is inside %eval() so MINOPERATOR and MINDELIMITER options still apply.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to evaluate your 'in' expression so that the ifn or ifc function sees it as a boolean value:

```
options symbolgen mprint mlogic minoperator;
%macro test /minoperator mindelimiter=',';
%let var1 = EXPORT;
%if &var1 in (EXPORT, TEST,TEST1) %then %let var_final1=1;
%put &=var_final1.;
%let var_final2 = %sysfunc(ifc(&var1= EXPORT,1,2));
%put &=var_final2;
%let var_final3 = %sysfunc(ifc(%eval(&var1 in (EXPORT, TEST,TEST1)),1,2));
%put &var_final3;
%mend;
%test;
```